# Windows Azure - Linux Virtual Machine - Opening a port for PgSQL

Tags: postgresql, azure, iptables

I'm trying to open a port on Windows Azure, and I have already:

1. Open a port on Azure portal using [NSG](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-nsg/)
2. Open a port on Linux virtual machine (iptables)
3. The port is open for all machines in the Windows Azure LAN network
4. I can't telnet from my remote host to Azure VM on PgSQL port (5432)
5. I have the same rule on iptables for 22 port and 8080 and those two rules are working...from my remote host..
6. I have also try to use tcpdump but I can't capture any packages for 5432 port when I try do telnet this port form my remote host...
7. No, my ISP don't block this port
8. I'm running out of ideas... if Azure is blocking the port, what will be point of setting NSG in the first place?

Comment: It doesn't sound like you're there yet, but make sure you edit the `pg_hba.conf` so that it will allow connections.  By default Pg only accepts connections from localhost.

Comment: I just try to open the port, the pg_hba.conf don't block the port, it block the connection to pgsql but don't close the port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem some time ago, maybe it will be useful for someone. Enyłej, when creating rules for azure firewall the numbers are very important:

if you have:

1000 allow-default-ssh

2000 allw-default-sth

don't create a rule with numbers like 1100 allow-smtp, start with a higher number like 2100.